# highlighting columns based on variable cell value vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to highlight the columns like a bar based on cell value automatically.

Eg. 3h -> highlight 3 columns beside the value with a fill color and bordered up like a bar.

1h -> highlight 1 column beside the value.

1.5h -> highlight one and half column and so on.

I tried with this code below, it works but it only highlight and add columns at B1. If I change to add the range to whole columns, the macros does not work.

```
`Sub TimingBars()
If Range("B1").Value <= 0 Then Exit Sub
With Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, 2 + Range("B1"))).EntireColumn
  .Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, 2 + Range("B1"))).Interior.Color = vbBlue

End With
End Sub`
```

Please help thanks!

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. You can search online for gantt chart templates for examples, even ones without VBA. Highlighting part of a cell is tricky, but I think it is usually done with Unicode whitespace characters.

Comment: I want to make use of the bar for scheduling purpose where I can move the bars around the timeline. I did consider using Gantt chart, but the bar cannot be extracted from the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to border the highlighted cell:

```
Sub TimingBars()
Dim i, BarLimit As Integer
Dim Rg, RgBar As Range
Set Rg = Range("B1:B100")

For Each cell In Rg
 If cell.Value > 0 Then

    Set RgBar = Range(Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1), Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + cell.Value))
    RgBar.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    With RgBar.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With RgBar.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With RgBar.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With RgBar.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
  End If

Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Sub TimingBars()
Dim i, BarLimit As Integer
Dim Rg As Range
Set Rg = Range("B1:B100") ' change this range as you want

For Each cell In Rg
  For i = 1 To cell.Value Step 1
   Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + i).Interior.Color = vbBlue
  Next i
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: however it cannot highlight half cell.

Comment: Hi it works thanks! just wondering, if I want to border the highlighted cell, which part of this vba do I add in the border vba at?

Comment: just put before next i

Comment: please see my other answer above